# SAFETYNET : com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16:

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using safety net in my application. It gives success response 15 to 20 times but after that it gives 
"com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16:" error. I checked my Api key in google console and it was fine.Please give me solution "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16:" this.

NOTE: This is not duplicate question.Already tried all solution provide in stack overflow.

Comment: [CommonStatusCodes#CANCELED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#public-static-final-int-canceled) -   Constant Value: 16 . The result was canceled either due to client disconnect or cancel()

Answer (score 0):

Probably you reached the limit.

> Regardless of the quota provisioned for your project, individual app instances are throttled to a maximum of 5 requests per minute. **If this limit is exceeded, all remaining requests during that minute return an error.**

https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation#quota-monitoring